# How could I set a universal time limit on any command line operation?

Tags: command-line

I would like to specify somewhere deep in the operating system that any command line command that takes longer than a specified amount of time should automatically be terminated or cancelled and return to the shell prompt.

It must be universal and deep in the terminal system so that no other application can take control of the command line and not be bound by the restriction.

How can I do this?

The specific reason is personal and would sound weird if I explained why but the explicit objective is I don’t want any command line process to take more than a very short period of time, ideally a tenth of a second or something seemingly immediate. I want to enforce my computing to be built from short processes and to adapt all processes that I need to do to short periods of time. If a process takes longer than that, I have to find a way to replace it or adapt my system in some way to make it meet the time limit. If there are processes going on in the background I never have to look at or think about, that’s fine. It should be the commands I see and am executing at the shell prompt.

I want to do this on Ubuntu Server, so I will not be running a GUI. I use 21.04 but the version number isn’t important to me.

Like this:

```
$ ls            # returns in .05 seconds
Documents
MyFiles
file.txt

$ python3 myscript.py     # returns in .09 seconds
This is the output of the Python script.

$ wget url            # went for .1 seconds whereupon the operating system terminated it
PROCESS TERMINATED DUE TO TIME LIMIT
```

Comment: To me, this looks like an [XY Question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem): Rather than ask about a problem, you are asking about a preferred solution. You may get better help if you ask about the underlying problem that a universal time limit seems to solve. Lots of commands happen behind the scenes -- a time limit might unexpectedly terminate your desktop or your network connection or have other unexpected impacts.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1370992/edit) and add more information about the real problem and the distro and version number of Linux you are using. Are you using the desktop or the server version?

Comment: Check out `cpu` in [`limits.conf`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man5/limits.conf.5.html).

Comment: So it is processes that you start yourself, and look at in a text screen (on the console or via ssh or something similar). It is straightforward for you to notice if they last longer than a second or less than a second. Start them prefixed with time: `time command -options parameters`. You will notice if they take longer than one second and you can turn them off manually. If shorter, you will get time used printed by the time command.

Comment: @sudodus Thanks for your suggestion but I’m sorry, that’s not what I am trying to do. I don’t need to find out how long it took. I want to stop it from ever going longer than a certain time, automatically.

Comment: I tried to understand but failed. Please explain again: Are there processes that are started automatically, that are running in the foreground and printing to the screen? Or something else? I thought that you wanted to find or develop commands that are fast enough and avoid commands that are too slow.

Comment: I just wrote above about “processes in the background” to mean, it’s ok if the computer is doing some process that the user is not aware of. That doesn’t need to be time limited. It’s just everything that happens in the terminal, at the command prompt, that the user does. If I enter a command into the shell, it returns before the time limit, or it gets cancelled and returns to the prompt before the time limit.

Comment: Is it OK for you if the processes leave opened files partially written and maybe corrupt?

Comment: I am open to exploring anything that makes it possible so if that’s necessary then yeah I’m interested, if it’s avoidable I can look into ways of fixing issues as I go further into this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130782/discussion-between-sudodus-and-peter-elbert).

Comment: Sure, I’m there. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Prefix with shellscript `check`

The shellscript `check`, that can be used to prefix any command line may look like this,

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" == "--debug" ]
then
 debug=true
 shift
else
 debug=false
fi

"$@" & pid=$!
sleep 0.1  # time (s) until kill
kill $pid 2> /dev/null
res="$?"

if $debug
then
 if [ $res -eq 0 ]
 then
  echo "killed at time-out: $@"
 else
  echo "finished gracefully: $@"
 fi
fi
```

Example 1

```
$ ./check --debug bash -c "while true;do date '+%s.%N';sleep 0.01;done"
1634944386.589977656
1634944386.603126888
1634944386.616089924
1634944386.629058026
1634944386.642334480
1634944386.655644267
1634944386.668289318
1634944386.681058710
killed at time-out: bash -c while true;do date '+%s.%N';sleep 0.01;done
```

Example 2

```
$ ./check --debug lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0 238,5G  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    0   500M  0 part 
├─sda2        8:2    0 139,4G  0 part 
├─sda3        8:3    0  1000M  0 part 
├─sda4        8:4    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5        8:5    0  89,7G  0 part /
└─sda6        8:6    0     8G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb           8:16   0   3,7T  0 disk 
├─sdb1        8:17   0   510M  0 part 
├─sdb2        8:18   0    30G  0 part 
├─sdb5        8:21   0     1M  0 part 
├─sdb6        8:22   0   100G  0 part 
├─sdb7        8:23   0   3,5T  0 part /media/multimed-2
└─sdb8        8:24   0     5G  0 part 
sr0          11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
nvme0n1     259:0    0 232,9G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0 232,9G  0 part 
└─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0     1M  0 part 
finished gracefully: lsblk
```

### Primitive custom shell `psh`

Another alternative, a primitive home-mode shell `psh` can be used for this purpose too.

- Advantage: You can run the commands directly without any extra prefix.
- Disadvantages: You can edit the command line, but there is no history and you have no access to the history of a standard shell, for example `bash`, zsh`,` tcsh`). Several other features of a the standard shell are missing too.

The bash shellscript `psh` and the python3 script `pin` should be made executable and copied, moved or linked into a directory in `PATH`, for example `/usr/local/bin`,

Start `psh`, run commands and exit from it with `exit`. The input is managed by `pin`, that uses `readline` in order to make it possible to edit the command line (more advanced than the built-in command `read` of `bash`).

`psh`,

```
#!/bin/bash

tmpf=$(mktemp)
curdir="$(pwd)"
cmd=
while true
do
# read -p "psh:$curdir> " cmd 2>&1
# echo "$cmd" > "$tmpf"
 pin "$curdir" "$tmpf"
#      cat "$tmpf"
 cmd=$(cat "$tmpf")
 if [ "$cmd" != "exit" ]
 then
  if [ "${cmd:0:3}" == "cd " ]
  then
   source "$tmpf"
   curdir="$(pwd)"
  else
   source "$tmpf" & pid=$!
   sleep 0.1  # time (s) until kill
   kill $pid 2> /dev/null
  fi
 else
  break
 fi
done 2> /dev/null
rm "$tmpf"
```

`pin`,

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from sys import argv
import rlcompleter
import readline
readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")
prompt = 'psh:{0} > '.format(argv[1])

f = open(argv[2], 'w')
cmd = input(prompt)
f.write('{0}\n'.format(cmd))  # write to first argument
```

Example:

```
sudodus@bionic64 /media/multimed-2/test/test0/temp/PeterElbert $ psh
psh:/media/multimed-2/test/test0/temp/PeterElbert >  while true;do date '+.%N';sleep 0.008;done
.753302869
.763750113
.773720876
.783983502
.794652755
.805570413
.816651252
.827621482
.838553391
.849516607
psh:/media/multimed-2/test/test0/temp/PeterElbert > ls -l
totalt 12
-rwxrwxr-x 1 sudodus sudodus 282 okt 23 01:18 check
-rwxrwxr-x 1 sudodus sudodus 255 okt 23 07:18 pin
-rwxrwxr-x 1 sudodus sudodus 438 okt 23 07:51 psh
psh:/media/multimed-2/test/test0/temp/PeterElbert > cd ..
psh:/media/multimed-2/test/test0/temp > exit
sudodus@bionic64 /media/multimed-2/test/test0/temp/PeterElbert $
```